# C#/C++: Create an additional bar on the top of the screen

Tags: c#, windows, visual-c++, taskbar

I try to write a program that shows an additional (task)bar on the top of the screen.
When other windows are maximized the bar should still be visible.

[Example here](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/3735/topbarg.jpg)

Is this possible in C# or C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create additional taskbars with [SHAppBarMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28VS.85%29.aspx), ABM_NEW.  You just need a window handle, a Winforms form will work fine.  Visit pinvoke.net if you want to do this from C# code.

Comment: Might there be a way to change an existing window into a docked one? Or do you need to create a new one?

Comment: Erm, sure.  The odds that this will actually be useful are very slim.  It ought to layout like a bar, it shouldn't have a frame.